# Current running through drain and source on an N channel MOSFET when the Vgs has not been met

Tags: solenoid, nmos, arduino-uno

[image]  I am attempting to create an electromagnetic paper airplane launcher. I am using a hall effect sensor to detect when a sled is passing a solenoid. I am using an Arduino Uno as my microcontroller so that once the hall effect sensor detects a magnetic field, an output voltage would be supplied to the gate pin on a logic-level n channel MOSFET.

As a safety feature, I have added a push-button. In my Arduino code, I am only allowing for the MOSFET to receive an input voltage once the button is being pressed and the hall effect sensor reads a magnetic field.

I tested everything today and found that current will be supplied to the solenoids as intended, but it will also be supplied when a magnetic field is present without having the button pressed.

I am not sure if this is a coding problem or not. Before hooking the solenoid to the mosfet, I used an led in place of it in order to see if anything was being sent through the MOSFET. When I used the LED, it worked as intended--only turning on when a magnetic field was present and the button was pressed down.

I was just wondering if anyone knew what might be happening when I changed the LED with a copper wire solenoid.

Here is my code:

```
int coil=1;//solenoid 1
int hs=2;//1st hall effect sensor

int button=3;

int coil2=4;//solenoid 2
int hs2=5;//2nd hall effect sensor


void setup() {
//establishes the hall effect sensor pins as input, the button pin as input, and the solenoid pin as output
pinMode(hs, INPUT);
pinMode(coil, OUTPUT);

pinMode(hs2, INPUT);
pinMode(coil2, OUTPUT);

pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if ((digitalRead(button)==HIGH)&&(digitalRead(hs)==LOW))//makes sure that the mosfet will only send current to solenoid once the button has been 
  {                                                       //been pressed and the hall effect sensor has been triggered.
    digitalWrite(coil, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(coil, LOW); 
  }

  if(digitalRead(hs2)==LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(coil2,HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(coil2, LOW); 
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic.

Comment: You might want to add some debounce/filtering to your hall and pushbutton inputs. Simply testing the input state as you are doing means your code could be fooled by noise and transients.

Comment: @winny here is the schematic for just one solenoid

Comment: the schematic shows the FET wired in a strange way, with gate and drain shorted. Is that accurate?

Comment: @tobalt no, it shuld show the drain and source shorted. That's my bad

Comment: @SamRembold But that makes even less sense. A MOSFET with drain and source shorted is just a small capacitor

Comment: That MOSFET has no ground reference. No wonder you can't control it. Its source needs to be connected to the system's ground.

Comment: @tobalt I am new to making schematics and so I was not sure which pins were what for the mosfet schematic. I think with this new schematic I have wired everything correctly so that the gate and drain are no longer shorted.

Comment: @Jonathan S. does this updated schematic solve the grounding issue?

Comment: There are still too many mistakes in the schematic to provide any answer. You still have a 330 ohm resistor on the MOSFET but it appears to be shorted. The drain just goes to a capacitor. The 3.3V and 5V pins of the Arduino are shorted, PWM D3 goes to GND. The pushbutton has a 330 ohm resistor on the contacts, which go to Vcc and GND.